# WPF ComboBox appearance query

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

In an example WPF Project (see code below) I have a `ComboBox` control that uses a `DataTemplate` to show its bound items (an array of `MyItem` objects). All this works as expected. Once an item is selected on the `ComboBox`, it shows the full DataTemplate for the selected item. What I would like to happen instead is

- When the user opens the `ComboBox`, it shows the full template for each bound item.
- Once an item is selected (and the `ComboBox` closes up) for it to only show a single property of the bound item, say the `Name` property of the `MyItem` object.

Here is some example code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MyItem[]
        {
            new MyItem() { Name = "Name1", Message="Message 1", Description = "Description 1" },
            new MyItem() { Name = "Name2", Message="Message 2", Description = "Description 2" },
            new MyItem() { Name = "Name3", Message="Message 3", Description = "Description 3" }

        };
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Place the Description/Message elements in another element that has conditional visibility:
    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ElementName=cboItems,Path=IsDropDownOpen,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

Comment: Where the ComboBox has a name set to "cboItems" and a BooleanToVisibilityConverter resource exists with the x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"

Comment: @Eric , thanks so much. Works great!